# How load text file with special characters in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a text file with the following info.
The file contains special characters í, ñ, ó

But when I run sql loader the special characters are not displayed

Text file

```
20200|Cobro Reconex de líneas mora
20900|ICE de Telecomunicación S
1000|MUÑOZ LEON JACINTO DAVID
```

Table LOAD_RESP

```
create table LOAD_RESP
(
  code         VARCHAR2(20),
  description  VARCHAR2(1000)
)
```

CTL File

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=(ALL, HEADER))
load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile test_output1.txt
badfile test_output1.bad
discardfile test_output1.dis
append
into table LOAD_RESP
fields terminated by '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
CODE        CHAR(20),
DESCRIPTION CHAR(1000)
)
```

SQL Loader

```
sqlldr user/pass control=CTLFile.ctl log=File.log rows=10000 direct=true errors=2147483648
```

Querying the table displays the question mark

How can I load this info along with the special characters?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your GUI client(pl/sql developer?) was configured with correct nls_lang?

Comment: And does your text file really contain utf8?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov   I checked the file and it is ISO-8859-1
`file -bi test_output1.txt
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`
I would have to transform the file to UTF8 or I would have to modify the characterset

Comment: Just for reference - From the docs: "During a direct path load, data conversion occurs on the client side rather than on the server side"

Comment: You can retry with `WE8ISO8859P1` option for `CHARACTERSET` instead of `UTF8` that should resolve the issue.

Comment: When the CSV file is ISO-8859-1 then you must specify `CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1`. Otherwise convert the file to UTF-8, e.g. with `iconv`. Note, Oracle character set name for UTF-8 is `AL32UTF8`, however for European characters it does not matter, it would be relevant only for some Asian and other exotic characters.